# Is there a graceful way to stop a long loop midway in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, signals, exit

**What I'm trying to do:**

What I have is a python script that runs indefinitely until the user decides to stop it. Ideally, I would like the entire program to stop when the user submits a `KeyboardInterrupt`. However, this only causes the program to skip immediately to the end and continue repeating itself. I've tried an alternative solution with synchronous threads but it either exhibits two behaviors:

1. Does the same exact thing as with the KeyboardInterrupt.
2. Stops the program *after* the while loop finishes.

The problem that I have with the second dilemma is that my while-loop takes a very long time to finish executing. Is there a graceful method for exiting a loop/script without having to wait for its completion? As in, as soon as a user submits crtl+c the program exits?

**My attempts:**

1.

```
thread_running = True

def function():

    while thread_running:

        # Do stuff that takes a long time

def termination():
    user_input = ''
    while user_input != 'e':
        user_input = input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("\n*** Hit 'e' to exit.\n")

    t1 = Thread(target = function)
    t2 = Thread(target = termination)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t2.join()
    thread_running = False
    print('\n*** Goodbye\n')
```

2. 

```
while True:

    try:

        # Execute long calculations

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise
```

3. 

```
while True:

    try:

        # Execute long calculations

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Full code for 3:

```
# Creates new temp log file
if os.path.exists('wp-logtemp.csv'):
    os.remove('wp-logtemp.csv')
os.mknod('wp-logtemp.csv')

while True:

    try:

        plan = 'userprof.jmx'

        # Run jmeter cli based on plan & output file
        os.system("./jmeter -n -t {} -l wp-logtemp.csv -J jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true".format(plan))

        # Array of elapsed times
        dataTime = []
        dataTime.clear()

        # Error counter
        err = 0

        # Open and read buffer
        with open('wp-logtemp.csv', 'r') as csvfile:

            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            # Skip header
            next(reader)

            for row in reader:
                # Converts from ms to s
                dataTime.append(float(row[1])/1000)
                if row[3] != '200':
                    err += 1

        # Sort times least to greatest
        dataTime.sort()

        # Sum all times
        timetot = sum(dataTime)

        # Number of rows
        requests = len(dataTime)

        # Calculate throughput (TP = number of requests / total time)
        through = requests / timetot
                    
        # Calculate average time (AV = total time / number of requests = 1/TP)
        timeavg = 1 / through

        # Calculate min
        timemin = (dataTime[0])

        # Calculate max
        timemax = (dataTime[len(dataTime)-1])

        # Intermidiary value for standev
        diff = sum(x - (timeavg**2) for x in dataTime)

        # Calculate standard deviation (s = sqrt((1/N-1)SUMOF(x-X)^2))
        standev = math.sqrt((1/(requests-1))*abs(diff))

        #Error % (false/total)
        erravg = float((err/requests)*100)

        print('**************')
        print('Number of requests = '+ str(requests))
        print('Total time = '+ str(timetot))
        print('Throughput = '+ str(through))
        print('Average time = '+ str(timeavg))
        print('Minimum time = '+ str(timemin))
        print('Maximum time = '+ str(timemax))
        print('Standard deviation = '+ str(standev))
        print('Error = '+ str(erravg))
        print('**************')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: The 2. attempt doesn't do anything (it just reraises the same exception). And your 3. solution should do exactly what you've described, doesn't it work?

Comment: No it's not working in my case. I will try it on another computer when I get the chance, maybe it's an issue with my system.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: When a keyboard interrupt is given, the loop will restart. In other words, the program does not exit.

Comment: 2. and 3. are identical. Regardless, so that is what you *want* it to do, or is it what it *is doing* that you don't want?

Comment: What I would like is for the keyboard interrupt to immediately exit the program. 1, 2, and 3 are not behaving in this manner. 2 and 3 only appear to restart the loop, preventing me from entering any console commands as the program is running indefinitely. 1 allows me to exit the loop, but only after it finishes completion. I would like for it to be immediate.

Comment: 3. works fine for me, i.e. breaks out of the loop without the error. Could you share the full code you are trying? If you just want to exit you can also try replacing `break` with `exit()`.

Comment: Just updated my post to include the full code for attempt 3

Comment: I found a not-so-graceful solution- hold down ctrl+c instead of just sending one interrupt signal. Very odd.

Comment: If you don’t attempt to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, does it work? If not caught, Control-C should terminate the program.

Comment: Negative, that's why I have the need to put a keryboardinterrupt handler in my code.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
import time
import threading
import sys

def check():
    while KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            break
            sys.exit(0)
        except:
            time.sleep(2)
threading.Thread(target=check).start()

def function():
    while True:
        # do stuff
function()
```

I added function that check for KeyboardInterrupt and if it happens, it should exit the program.

Hope it will work ;)

Comment: `while KeyboardInterrupt:`? `try: break`? What?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's just nonsense that follows python syntax. And by pure luck doesn't fail at the start.